# where can I find a chart or data showing total Multibit dowloads?

Tags: multibit

I'm looking to see the total downloads for Multibit like what was in the Coindesk article earlier this year. Ideally I'd see them by month. Any sources out there?

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis Would you mind linking it? I was unable to find data less than a year old.

Comment: @NickODell: https://multibit.org/blog/2014/03/10/multibit-downloads-reach-1.5m.html

Answer (score 1):

It's outdated but as @GeorgeKimionis mentioned in a comment, Multibit published some data on their blog:

https://multibit.org/blog/2014/03/10/multibit-downloads-reach-1.5m.html

And in case they take down their blog, here is the data:

[image]

```
Month   Downloads
Apr to Oct 2011 tiny
Nov 2011    200
Dec 2011    500
Jan 2012    600
Feb 2012    700
Mar 2012    800
Apr 2012    1,000
May 2012    1,200
Jun 2012    1,500
Jul 2012    2,200
Aug 2012    3,000
Sep 2012    3,300
Oct 2012    3,600
Nov 2012    3,900
Dec 2012    4,200
Jan 2013    4,600
Feb 2013    8,800
Mar 2013    26,000
Apr 2013    73,200
May 2013    50,600
Jun 2013    34,100
Jul 2013    75,000
Aug 2013    103,500
Sep 2013    71,400
Oct 2013    97,200
Nov 2013    330,000
Dec 2013    298,600
Jan 2014    131,900
Feb 2014    132,400
(incomplete) Mar 2014   53,200
Total   1,517,200
```